# How to insert null value by entity framework in MySQL nullable date column?

Tags: mysql, entity-framework

I have a database in MySQL 8.0.15 and there is a table in the database which includes a nullable DATE column like shown below;

```
CREATE TABLE `sayaclar` (
  `sayac_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `daire_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sayac_no` varchar(20) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `urun_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `marka_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `model_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `montaj_endeks` decimal(18,6) DEFAULT '0.000000',
  `kc` decimal(3,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `rad_gucu` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `rad_uz` decimal(4,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `mahal` varchar(45) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `aktif` bit(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT b'1',
  `aktif_tarihi` date NOT NULL,
  `pasif_tarihi` date DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`sayac_id`),
  KEY `fk_sayaclar_daire_id` (`daire_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_sayaclar_daire_id` FOREIGN KEY (`daire_id`) REFERENCES `daireler` (`daire_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

and this is my insert function;

```
sayaclar meter = new sayaclar
{
   aktif = true,
   aktif_tarihi = DateTime.Now,
   pasif_tarihi = null,
   urun_id = model.urun_id,
   marka_id = model.marka_id,
   model_id = modelId,
   montaj_endeks = mountedIndex,
   sayac_no = meterNumber,
   daire_id = flatId
};
meter = ctx.sayaclar.Add(meter);
ctx.SaveChanges();
return meter.sayac_id;
```

When I tried to insert a record to this table the function throws `EntityValidationError` which says `pasif_tarihi is required`

Comment: Just remove this line **pasif_tarihi = null,**

Comment: I tried this but not worked

Comment: The `EntityValidationError` means there is something inside your `sayaclar` class (like `Required` attribute) or fluent API (like `IsRequired()` call) which is telling EF that the `pasif_tarihi` property is required, event it's of type `DateTime?`. It can 't be said from the posted code. Database table definition is irrelevant, the exception is from the model.

Comment: Yes, pasif_tarihi property is like
```public Nullable<System.DateTime> pasif_tarihi { get; set; }``` the problem is this?

Comment: Thank you @Ivan Stoev. I removed Nullable statement and it works

Comment: After that fixing I can't handle null date value which is retrieving from database. The date value is coming null from database but the property of ```System.DateTime pasif_tarihi``` in my model can't store null date value because it is not ```Nullable<System.DateTime>```. How can I fix this? @Ivan Stoev

Comment: Actually you should keep the property type `Nullable<DateTime>` and remove the `Required` attribute. I mean, most likely the `sayaclar` class contains something like `[Required] public Nullable<DateTime> pasif_tarihi  {get; set}`, right?

Comment: Already there is no ```[Required]``` attribute on my property. If I put the ```Nullable``` statement to the property, throws ```required``` exception when I tried to insert; If I remove ```Nullable``` statement, the property doesn't store null value of date when I run the select function. Because some records has null date.